# Black full screen background

Tags: java

I am learning game development in java. I just learnt to make a full screen, the text "Hello World" is appearing, but the backgrounds is black. I set it to blue in the ' setFullScreen() 'method in the GD class. I cannot find the heart of the problem as I found no problems in the code, as per my knowledge.

Class GD:

```
package gd;
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GD {
private GraphicsDevice vc;
public GD(){
    GraphicsEnvironment      env=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    vc=env.getDefaultScreenDevice();


}
public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm,JFrame window){
window.setUndecorated(true);
window.setResizable(false);
window.setBackground(Color.RED);
window.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
window.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);
  if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()==true ){
        try{
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);

        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

 }
  public Window getFullScreen(){

  return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
  } 
  public void restoreScreen(){
      Window w=vc.getFullScreenWindow();
  if(w!=null){
      w.dispose();
  }vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
  }

  }
```

Class Game(main class)

```
package gd;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class game extends JFrame {
public static void main(String[]args){
DisplayMode dm=new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
game g= new game();
g.run(dm);
}


public void run(DisplayMode dm)
{

    GD s=new GD();
    try{
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        }catch(Exception ex){

    }finally{
            s.restoreScreen();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
 } 
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
 g.drawString("Hello World",200,200);
    }
}
```

[The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv2Qa.png)

Comment: can you post the current screen appearance to understand it.

Comment: I have added the output

Comment: repaste the output with "hello world".

Comment: Please try to keep this site civil. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, but now I updated the image.